# Spark RDD - CountByValue - Map type - order by key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

From spark RDD - countByValue is returning Map Datatype and want to sort by key ascending/ descending .

```
val s =  flightsObjectRDD.map(_.dep_delay / 60 toInt).countByValue() // RDD type is action and returning Map datatype
  s.toSeq.sortBy(_._1)
```

The above code is working as expected. But countByValue itself have implicit sorting . How can i implement that way?

[image]

Comment: Suggest you change your handle to Learn Big Data

Comment: I think I answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You exit the Big Data realm and get into Scala itself. And then into all those structures that are immutable, sorted, hashed and mutable, or a combination of these. I think that is the reason for the -1 initially. Nice folks out there, anyway.

Take this example, the countByValue returns a Map to the Driver, so only of interest for small amounts of data. Map is also (key, value) pair but with hashing and immutable. So we need to manipulate it. This is what you can do. First up you can sort the Map on the key in ascending order.

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("HR",5),("RD",4),("ADMIN",5),("SALES",4),("SER",6),("MAN",8),("MAN",8),("HR",5),("HR",6),("HR",5)))
val map = rdd1.countByValue

val res1 = ListMap(map.toSeq.sortBy(_._1):_*) // ascending sort on key part of Map
res1: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[(String, Int),Long] = Map((ADMIN,5) -> 1, (HR,5) -> 3, (HR,6) -> 1, (MAN,8) -> 2, (RD,4) -> 1, (SALES,4) -> 1, (SER,6) -> 1)
```

However, you cannot apply reverse or descending logic on the key as it is hashing. Next best thing is as follows:

```
val res2 = map.toList.sortBy(_._1).reverse
val res22 = map.toSeq.sortBy(_._1).reverse

res2: List[((String, Int), Long)] = List(((SER,6),1), ((SALES,4),1), ((RD,4),1), ((MAN,8),2), ((HR,6),1), ((HR,5),3), ((ADMIN,5),1))
res22: Seq[((String, Int), Long)] = ArrayBuffer(((SER,6),1), ((SALES,4),1), ((RD,4),1), ((MAN,8),2), ((HR,6),1), ((HR,5),3), ((ADMIN,5),1))
```

But you cannot apply the `.toMap` against the `.reverse` here, as it will hash and lose the sort. So, you must make a compromise.

Comment: what about this solution : will that work ? val orderedMap = TreeMap(s.toSeq.sortBy(_._1).reverse:_*)

Comment: I see you did not try, but fixing the syntax and applying your .reverse does not work: command-311042925470641:16: error: value reverse is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[(String, Int),Long]
val orderedMap = TreeMap(map.toSeq.sortBy(_._1):_*).reverse
                                                    ^

Comment: And also TreeMap is excessive approach.